# Error with observeEvent and a plot created with echarts4r (shiny app)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, echarts

Hi and thanks for reading me

Im working with a neural network model for time series in shiny. I want to create an app that generates a forecast after pressing a button, but it only stays loading and does not generate any graph (I already tried the script outside of a shiny app and it works correctly). Am I using the ObserveEvent wrong or is there something I am missing? thanks for your help

The code (and data) is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(forecast)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)

datos <- data.frame(
  Servicio = sample(c("Servicio 1", "Servicio 2", "Servicio 3"), 162, replace = TRUE),
  Año_mes = seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("2020-05-31"), by = "quarter"),
  servs = rnorm(162, mean = 500)
) |> 
  setNames(c("Servicio", "Año_mes", "Número de Servicios"))

datos1 <- datos |> 
  group_by(Año_mes, Servicio) |> 
  summarise(total = sum(`Número de Servicios`)) 

datos_select <- datos |> 
  group_by(Servicio) |> 
  summarise(total = sum(datos$`Número de Servicios`))




datos_select <- datos_select$Servicio
datos_select

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 6,
    selectInput("var",
                "Escoge un servicio a modelar", choices = datos_select
    ),
    numericInput("rezagosnoest", "Escoge un número de rezagos no estacionales:",1, min = -1000, max = 1000),
    numericInput("rezagossiest", "Escoge un número de rezagos estacionales:",1, min = -1000, max = 1000),
    numericInput("neuronas", "Escoge la cantidad de neuronas usadas para el cálculo:",1, min = 1, max = 1000),
    numericInput("futuros", "Escoge el número de periodos (meses) a pronosticar:",1, min = 1, max = 1000),
    actionBttn(
      inputId = "modelar",
      label = "Generar pronóstico", 
      style = "bordered",
      color = "success",
      icon = icon("sliders")
    )),
  column(width = 6,
         addSpinner(echarts4rOutput("grafico"), spin = "folding-cube", color = "#4DAF4A"))
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
  observeEvent(
    input$modelar,{
      reactive({
        
        filtrado <- datos1 |> 
          filter(Servicio == input$var) 
        temporal <- ts(filtrado$total, start = 2017, frequency = 12)
        set.seed(50)
        modelo <- nnetar(temporal, p=input$rezagossiest,P=input$rezagosnoest,
                         size=input$neuronas)
        nnetforecast <- forecast(modelo, h = input$futuros, PI = T)
        df_inf <- data.frame(nnetforecast$lower)
        df_sup <- data.frame(nnetforecast$upper)
        df_forecast <- data.frame(nnetforecast$mean, df_sup$X90., df_inf$X10.) |> 
          setNames( c("Pronostico", "Banda superior", "Banda inferior") )
        filtrado1 <- bind_rows(filtrado, df_forecast)
        filtrado2 <- data.frame(
          Fecha = seq(as.Date(datos1$Año_mes[1]), (as.Date(tail(datos1$Año_mes, 1))+ months(input$futuros)), by = "month"),
          filtrado1$total, filtrado1$Pronostico, filtrado1$`Banda superior`, filtrado1$`Banda inferior`
        ) |> 
          setNames(c("Fecha", "Valor", "pronostico", "Banda superior", "Banda inferior"))
        
        output$grafico <- renderEcharts4r({
          
          filtrado2 |> 
            e_charts(Fecha) |> 
            e_line(Valor, symbol = "none") |> 
            e_line(pronostico, symbol = "none") |> 
            #e_y_axis(min = 30000, max = 71000) |> 
            e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") |> 
            e_band(min = `Banda inferior`, max = `Banda superior`) |> 
            e_color(color = c("#4065a1", "#a14040", "#d6c847", "#d6c847") ) 
          
        })
        
      })
      
    }
    
    
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `reactive` inside `observeEvent`. I am not sure if creation of `filtrado2` in your code is correct because `Fecha` returns output of length 485 whereas rest of the columns are only of length 43. I am not sure what is the right values you want there for now I am just using dates from `filtrado1$Año_mes`.

```
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(forecast)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)

datos <- data.frame(
  Servicio = sample(c("Servicio 1", "Servicio 2", "Servicio 3"), 162, replace = TRUE),
  Año_mes = seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("2020-05-31"), by = "quarter"),
  servs = rnorm(162, mean = 500)
) |> 
  setNames(c("Servicio", "Año_mes", "Número de Servicios"))

datos1 <- datos |> 
  group_by(Año_mes, Servicio) |> 
  summarise(total = sum(`Número de Servicios`)) 

datos_select <- datos |> 
  group_by(Servicio) |> 
  summarise(total = sum(datos$`Número de Servicios`))




datos_select <- datos_select$Servicio
datos_select

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 6,
    selectInput("var",
                "Escoge un servicio a modelar", choices = datos_select
    ),
    numericInput("rezagosnoest", "Escoge un número de rezagos no estacionales:",1, min = -1000, max = 1000),
    numericInput("rezagossiest", "Escoge un número de rezagos estacionales:",1, min = -1000, max = 1000),
    numericInput("neuronas", "Escoge la cantidad de neuronas usadas para el cálculo:",1, min = 1, max = 1000),
    numericInput("futuros", "Escoge el número de periodos (meses) a pronosticar:",1, min = 1, max = 1000),
    actionBttn(
      inputId = "modelar",
      label = "Generar pronóstico", 
      style = "bordered",
      color = "success",
      icon = icon("sliders")
    )),
  column(width = 6,echarts4rOutput("grafico"))
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
  observeEvent(
    input$modelar,{
         
        filtrado <- datos1 |> 
          filter(Servicio == input$var) 
        temporal <- ts(filtrado$total, start = 2017, frequency = 12)
        set.seed(50)
        modelo <- nnetar(temporal, p=input$rezagossiest,P=input$rezagosnoest,
                         size=input$neuronas)
        nnetforecast <- forecast(modelo, h = input$futuros, PI = T)
        df_inf <- data.frame(nnetforecast$lower)
        df_sup <- data.frame(nnetforecast$upper)
        df_forecast <- data.frame(nnetforecast$mean, df_sup$X90., df_inf$X10.) |> 
          setNames( c("Pronostico", "Banda superior", "Banda inferior") )
        filtrado1 <- bind_rows(filtrado, df_forecast)
        filtrado2 <- data.frame(
          Fecha = filtrado1$Año_mes,
          filtrado1$total, filtrado1$Pronostico, filtrado1$`Banda superior`, filtrado1$`Banda inferior`
        ) |> 
          setNames(c("Fecha", "Valor", "pronostico", "Banda superior", "Banda inferior"))
        
        output$grafico <- renderEcharts4r({
          
          filtrado2 |> 
            e_charts(Fecha) |> 
            e_line(Valor, symbol = "none") |> 
            e_line(pronostico, symbol = "none") |> 
            #e_y_axis(min = 30000, max = 71000) |> 
            e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") |> 
            e_band(min = `Banda inferior`, max = `Banda superior`) |> 
            e_color(color = c("#4065a1", "#a14040", "#d6c847", "#d6c847") ) 
          
        
      })
      
    }
    
    
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it already works. You are right, I had an error in my code, but you saved my life anyway, I thank you very much

Comment: @PorkChop Is there an alternative to observeEvent with heavy operations?

Comment: @JorgeHernández In general, heavy operations should be avoided in the observer, you may have memory leaks. You should aim to return a value, so use `reactives` instead